# Using Hanumaninstitute. Libmpv. Avalonia wrapped in Ubuntu running error "Unable to load the DLL 'libmpv. 2'"

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, mpv

I in my avalonia project reference Hanumaninstitute LibMpv. Avalonia and Hanumaninstitute LibMpv in Windows can run normally, But I published to the Ubuntu or a copy of the project on Ubuntu running after an error Unhandled exception. System. DLLNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libmpv.2 ' The specified module could not be found.

I tried to copy the project into the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory with the same error. I try to copy the libmpv.so file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to the project directory, but the result is still unable to find 'libmpv.2', what is the solution.

[image: error]